# How to move bytes of a variable in assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86

I have an assignment for my computer organization class where I need to move each byte of a 4 byte hex value assigned to a variable named i1 (0xaabbccee) into 4 different variables (c1, c2, c3, c4). How do I tell which byte is high order and which is low order, because it wants the bytes to be stored into specific variable determined by their order. After determining the order of the bytes, how do I store only ONE byte of the long i1 into a different variable?

Comment: why is this tagged C++? Are you using a C++ program that's linked to the assembly program, are you using some inline assembly? Are the variables just some local C++ variables in a function?

Comment: x86 processors use little-endian ordering.

Comment: hex is a *character string* representation for numeric data; are you working with *character strings* or *numbers*?

Comment: shift and mask, look up shift and/or rotate instructions and look up the and instruction.

Comment: if the 32 bits are contained in a single register when you start then the assumption is that byte ordering is set as there are no bytes yet it is a 32 bit quantity, the low order bits on the bottom the higher order bits on the top, you shift and mask 8 bits at a time accordingly.  possible to do with exchange instructions instead of shifting, but examine each of these instructions and it should become obvious

Comment: variables dont exist in assembly, variables are a high level language concept.  bits is bits you have 32 bits and want to turn it into 4 8 bit quantities, depending on what registers you use or your use case this could mean padding or sign extending the other bits in the destination register.  and/or if these are coming from memory and then going back what is the size of the locations you are using for each?

Answer (score 4):

If you use C++ types of the correct size to hold your values:

```
uint32_t hex_val = 0xaabbccee;
```

then you don't have to worry about endian-ness, just peel off the values one-by-one:

```
uint8_t bytes[4];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    bytes[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(hex_val & 0xff);
    hex_val  >>= 8;
}
```

Comment: A byte is 8 bits wide (on x86).  You want `hex_val >>= 8;`  Also, `& 0xFF` is redundant before static_cast to `uint8_t`.  Since the x86 asm the OP wants is just 8-bit `mov` stores, using just `static_cast` is more appropriate.  (I assume they wanted to do this with inline asm and forgot to say so; it looks like the reverse of a recent question about merging c1..4 bytes into a dword `i1`: [Confused how to access C++ variable within assembly code](//stackoverflow.com/a/59905150))

Comment: @PeterCordes Quite right, thanks. Last time I did this it was for nibbles not bytes. I'd keep the `& 0xff` for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can use anonymous structs inside anonymous unions. So, let the compiler with bitfields do the job:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    union
    {
        unsigned int i1;
        struct { unsigned c4:8, c3:8, c2:8, c1:8; };
    };

    i1 = 0xaabbccee;
    cout << "i1: " << hex << i1 << endl;
    cout << "c1: " << hex << c1 << endl;
    cout << "c2: " << hex << c2 << endl;
    cout << "c3: " << hex << c3 << endl;
    cout << "c4: " << hex << c4 << endl;
}
```

Comment: That's not valid C++ as it's writing to one member of the union and then reading a different (inactive, out of lifetime) one; e.g. see the "Member lifetime" section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union. Also, unsigned int is only required to be 16 bits wide, the constant might not fit; if you mean uint32_t, say it.

Comment: @Sasha: It's valid in MSVC; it (like GNU C++) does define the behaviour of union type-punning.  And when targeting x86, the types will have those sizes.  But sure, fair point that this isn't portable ISO C++.

Comment: You don't really need bitfields; you could more easily use an anonymous struct of four `unsigned char` members.  Also, there's no reason to use `std::endl` here; you don't need to flush cout before some slow computation; you're printing something else right away, so a normal `"\n"` would be fine.